# SQL Query for Select Sequence Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Query for Select Sequence Numbers

In SQL server, I want to select rows based on sequence numbers. For example I am having data as below:

```
ID RowNos
A  1
B  2
X  NULL
C  4
D  5
Y  NULL
E  7
F  8
G  9
H  11
I  13
```

Query Should return

```
ID NextID 
A  B      -- Since RowNos 1,2 is in sequence
C  D      -- Since RowNos 4,5 is in sequence
E  G      -- Since RowNos 7,8,9 is in sequence
```

I don't have idea to start this query. Otherwise I'll post my trial too.

Comment: Your example seems somewhat unclear to me. Are you looking at sequence of `ID` or `RowNos` - if the latter is it guaranteed that they are unique and will be sequential except for the intervening `NULL`? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith,  I want to retrieve the ID and Next ID based on the sequence. For example, 1,2 is the sequence because 3 is missing So A(1) Is the ID and B(2) is the Next ID.

Comment: Is RowNos unique for not null values? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes Its unique..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID CHAR(1), RowNos INT)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('X', NULL),
    ('C', 4), ('D', 5), ('Y', NULL),
    ('E', 7), ('F', 8), ('G', 9),
    ('H', 11), ('I', 13)

SELECT MIN(ID), MAX(ID)
FROM (
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNos)
    FROM @t
) t
WHERE RowNos IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY RowNos - rn
HAVING MIN(ID) != MAX(ID)
```

Output:

```
---- ----
A    B
C    D
E    G
```

Answer (score 0):

to select them ordered should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE RowNos IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RowNos ASC;
```